# Cannot Import defined module in Project Folder - VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, fastapi

Below is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\runpy.py", line
> 194, in _run_module_as_main
> return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\runpy.py", line
> 87, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\Scripts\uvicorn.exe_*main**.py",
> line 7, in    File
> "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 1128, in **call**
> return self.main(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 1053, in main
> rv = self.invoke(ctx)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 1395, in invoke
> return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\click\core.py",
> line 754, in invoke
> return _*callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py",
> line 437, in main
> run(app, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\main.py",
> line 463, in run
> server.run()   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py",
> line 60, in run
> return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\asyncio\runners.py",
> line 44, in run
> return loop.run_until_complete(main)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 616, in run_until_complete
>
> return future.result()   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py",
> line 67, in serve
> config.load()   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py",
> line 458, in load
> self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py",
> line 24, in import_from_string
> raise exc from None   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py",
> line 21, in import_from_string
> module = importlib.import_module(module_str)   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Anaconda3\envs\pycaret_venv8\lib\importlib_*init**.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 1014, in _gcd_import   File
> "", line 991, in _find_and_load   File
> "", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
> File "", line 671, in *load_unlocked
>
> File "", line 843, in
> exec_module   File "", line 219, in
> *call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Documents\GitHub\project_path.\project_name_*init**.py",
> line 14, in 
> from .routes import integration_router   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Documents\GitHub\project_path.\project_name\routes_*init**.py", line 12, in 
> from .user import user   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Documents\GitHub\project_path.\project_name\routes\user.py",
> line 16, in 
> from ..config.db import conn, session   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Documents\GitHub\project_path.\project_name\config\db.py",
> line 20, in 
> from ..utilities.logger import Logger   File "C:\Users\Saoni_Deb\Documents\GitHub\project_path.\project_name\utilities\logger.py",
> line 17, in        from utilities.logger_config import config
>
> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'**

Utilities is a module defined within my fastapi project folder.
What could be the possible reason for python not recognizing my project module here?

Edit:
The structure is as below:

Project_name
|
|------Utilities--init.py, logger.py, logger_config.py
|
|------Other module--file1.py,file2.py

I am starting the project using -- Uvicorn Project_name:app
The following imports are used in the logger.py file:

```
import logging.config
from utilities.logger_config import config
```

**Update:**
Issue resolved after uninstalling certain packages to remove conflict and redefining the python Interpreter path and environment

TIA

Comment: Please share what your file/folder structure looks like, how your relevant imports are written, and how you are starting your application.

Comment: The structure is as below:
Project_name
|
|------Utilities--init.py, logger.py, logger_config.py
|  
|------Other module--file1.py,file2.py

I am starting the project using -- Uvicorn Project_name:app